# Difficulties connecting to app.js file with node/nodemon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodemon

So I've inserted pictures of my vsCode, I'm trying to use node (or nodemon, which never seems to work for me) how ever I get an error message each time. I've even tried moving around my code, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

[image: my app.js file]
[image: hotel.js file which I don't think has anything to do with why i'm not getting a collections but decided to add anyway just to be safe]

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

Change line 2 of `app.js` into

`const hotel = require('./models/hotel.js/hotel');`

The reason you got an error in the console was because the `require` directory is wrong.